# jinja2 - get rid of empty lines when variables are not defined

Tags: templates, ansible, jinja2

I always get a newline when a variable is not defined in the following example:

Playbook:

```yaml
- name: testplaybook jinja2
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    testvalue1: "A"
    testvalue2: "B"
    testvalue4: "D"
    testvalue5: "E"

  tasks:

    - name: test jinja2 template
      local_action:
        module: template
        src: testtemplate2.xml.j2
        dest: testtemplate2_output.xml
        trim_blocks: no
```

testtemplate2.xml.j2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <instances>
    <testinstance staticvaluex=X
      staticvaluey=Y
      staticvaluez=Z
{% if testvalue1 is defined %}      value1="{{ testvalue1 }}"{% endif %}
{% if testvalue2 is defined %}      value2="{{ testvalue2 }}"{% endif %}
{% if testvalue3 is defined %}      value3="{{ testvalue3 }}"{% endif %}
{% if testvalue4 is defined %}      value4="{{ testvalue4 }}"{% endif %}
{% if testvalue5 is defined %}      value5="{{ testvalue5 }}"{% endif %}
    />
  </instances>
</configuration>
```

In the example we don't specify testvalue3 so the output testtemplate2_output.xml contains a newline:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <instances>
    <testinstance staticvaluex=X
      staticvaluey=Y
      staticvaluez=Z
      value1="A"
      value2="B"

      value4="D"
      value5="E"
    />
  </instances>
</configuration>
```

How can I get rid of this new line?

I tried a lot with `{%-` or `+%}` or `trim_blocks` etc. but nothing seems to work.
Of course this should then work with any of these lines because any of these variables could be empty and there must not be a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this j2 with this playbook does the job:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: test jinja2 template
      local_action:
        module: template
        src: testtemplate2.xml.j2
        dest: testtemplate2_output.xml
```

file j2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <instances>
    <testinstance staticvaluex=X
      staticvaluey=Y
      staticvaluez=Z
{%- if testvalue1 is defined %}      
      value1="{{ testvalue1 }}"
{% else %}

{% endif %}
{% if testvalue2 is defined %}
      value2="{{ testvalue2 }}"
{% endif %}
{% if testvalue3 is defined %}
      value3="{{ testvalue3 }}"
{% endif %}
{% if testvalue4 is defined %}
      value4="{{ testvalue4 }}"
{% endif %}
{% if testvalue5 is defined %}
      value5="{{ testvalue5 }}"
{% endif %}
    />
  </instances>
</configuration>
```

result:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <instances>
    <testinstance staticvaluex=X
      staticvaluey=Y
      staticvaluez=Z      
      value1="A"
      value2="B"
      value4="D"
      value5="E"
    />
  </instances>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working. I should have started with putting the if/endif blocks on separate lines instead on oneline.